# If a class matches another class using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a large site, where on each page one of the body classes matches the class of an menu item. What I am trying to do is write a simple jQuery function that will check what the body class is... then search the menu and if the list item has a class of the same name, it adds an active class to the list item.

The body has several classes too... which is why I thought this would work, using `is()`...

```
var matchingClass = $('body').attr('class');
if ( $('.sub-menu-container ul li').is('.'+matchingClass) ) {
    $(this).addClass('active');
}
```

But it didn't do anything. How can I rewrite this so it will get the body class, then search the page for the menu item of the same class name and add a class?

Thanks

Comment: `$('body.menuClassName ul li.menuClassName').addClass('active');` or simply skip the `active` class and style using CSS in the stylesheet.

Comment: I changed my code, slightly... thinking this would be better. Still no luck.

Comment: I mean it should work. `$('body').attr('class')` brings back `blog blog-overview galleries` so the if statement should check if the li element has one of these classes... if so... adds the active class.

Comment: After re-reading your code, I think the `$.filter()` method will do what you want and is very concise. See the first part of my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Although the other answer below will work in a fashion, I think this is closer to what you're trying to do:

```
var cls = $('#test').attr('class').split(/\s+/);

$('div[class]').filter('.' + cls.join('.')).addClass('active1');
$('div[class]').filter(':not(.' + cls.join('.') + ')').addClass('inactive1');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/DMxUx/5

Or using your code:

```
var matchingClass = $('body').attr('class');

$('.sub-menu-container ul li')
    .filter('.' + matchingClass.split(/\s+/).join('.'))
    .addClass('active');
```

And if in case I misunderstood (again), if you only want to match *one* `body` class to the `li`:

```
$('div[class]').filter('.' + cls.join(',.')).addClass('active1');
$('div[class]').filter(':not(.' + cls.join(',.') + ')').addClass('inactive1');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/DMxUx/6/

---

Use [`$.hasClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/hasclass/) and a `for` loop:

```
var cls = $('#test').attr('class').split(/\s+/);

console.log(cls);

$('div[class]').each(function ea(){
    var matches = 0;

    for (var i = 0; i < cls.length; i++) {
        if ($(this).hasClass(cls[i])) {
            matches++;
        }
    }

    if (cls.length == matches) {
        $(this).addClass('active').removeClass('inactive');
    } else {
        $(this).addClass('inactive').removeClass('active');
    }
});
```

Using:

```
<div id='test' class='test1 test2 test3'></div>
<div class='test1 test2 test3'></div>
<div class='test1 test3 test2'></div>
<div class='test1 test3'></div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/DMxUx/2

Answer (score 0):

If I am understanding correctly, you are looking for a way to find out if a menu item matches *any* of the classes that exist on the body. To do that you will probably want to split the body element class into all of the classNames that it contains.

```js
var classNames = document.body.className.split(/\s+/);
```

Once you have that, you can check each one one its own.

```js
var $menu = $(".sub-menu-container.works ul");
$.each(classNames, function(idx, value) {
    var $menuItem = $menu.find("." + $.trim(value));

    if ($menuItem.length) {
        // We found our menu item
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.sub-menu-container ul li').each(function() {
        var classes = this.classList;
        for (var i=0,len=classes.length; i<len; i++) {
            if ($('body').hasClass(classes[i])) {
                $(this).addClass('active');
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: So this is what worked... but seems ridiculously over the top. I can't see why my original code didn't work.

Comment: I'm not sure this is doing what you think it's doing, unless I misunderstand. There's only one check it has to pass, so once your `li` has exactly one class it shares with the `body`, it's going to add the `active` class. I was under the assumption you wanted to match more than one class? (I've added another version of the `filter` method to match what you've got here.)

Answer (score -1):

Think this might be what you're after

```
// First get all classes of body by splitting them into an array
var classList =$('body').attr('class').split(/\s+/);
$.each( classList, function(index, bodyClass){
    // loop through each bodyClass and add active to all matching elements.
    $('.sub-menu-container ul li.' + bodyClass).addClass('active');
});
```

Comment: that would just check that matchingClass has a truthy value

Comment: Yes.  Correct, if there is no class it will return `undefined` and hence fail the if.

Comment: Although on re-reading the question I think I may have oversimplified things.  It seems there could be several classes on the body and only one of them is needed to check.